# Is this back program complete?

Tags: strength-training, back

I have some years of strength training experience but haven't lifted in a couple of years.

To get back on track I am following a Starting Strengh/Stronglifts hybrid (basically stronglifts 3x5).

I have always had a bad posture (arched back and forward head), and being a desk jockey isn't helping it either. I always notice that when my (back) strength goes up, my posture improves.

That is why I decided to do a little extra for the back. Build a little bit of extra muscle and extra strength by introducing a dedicated back day.

This is the program I came up with:

```
Pullup negs (alternate between neutral, pronated and supinated grip): 10x1  
Deadstop db rows (with straps so I can focus more on lats): 3x8  
Snatch grip high pull: 8x3  
Seated cable rows: 5x8  
Wide grip lat pull down (alternate BTN and front): 3x15
```

I must say I haven't gone to failure yet on any exercise, but it is a heavy program. I am pretty exhausted the hours after I have completed this workout. More than on my strength days.

My question is: I know that DOMS is not a measure of an effective workout, but with this amount of volume and intensity I would expect to get at least a little bit sore. **What do you think of this program? Would you think it is effective in building strength and/or size?**

So I want to know if it would be effective for strength/size not whether or not it would improve my posture.

Comment: For back strength it seems like a lot of volume. I find that Rack pulls and pullups are more than enough especially if you combine these with a strength program. Rack pulls will definitely overload the upper back and help your posture.

Comment: I do deadlifts every other day on my main program.